# Slash + asterisk inside code results in the rest of the line commented out

Tags: support

How can I prevent this from happening. All I want is normal code - no comment.

```
/account/** = ssl, authc
```

Here nothing is grayed out in a comment-like fashion, but on stackoverflow `/** = ssl, authc` is.

Comment: What language is this in? In some languages thats how you start a comment

Comment: I fixed it.​​​​